# Python Pandas - Faster Way to Iterate Through Categories in Data While Removing Outliers (Without For Loop)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 105],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'cash','items', 20],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'card','sales$', 190],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'card','items', 40],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 75],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'cash','items', 10],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'card','sales$', 170],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'card','items', 35],
        [5123, '2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 1000],
        [5123, '2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'cash','items', 500],
        [5123, '2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'card','sales$', 150],
        [5123, '2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'card','items', 20]]

columns = ['Store', 'Date', 'Payment Method', 'Attribute', 'Value']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns)
```

| Store | Date | Payment Method | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 105 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | items | 20 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 190 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | items | 40 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 75 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | items | 10 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 170 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | items | 35 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 1000 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | cash | items | 500 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 150 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | card | items | 20 |

I would like to filter outliers and replace them with the average value from the preceding 2 days.
My "outlier rule" is such: if a value for an attribute/payment method is more than twice as big, or smaller than half as big, as the average value for that attribute/payment method from the preceding two days, then replace that outlier with the average value from the preceding two days. Otherwise, leave the value. In this case, all values should remain except for the $1000 sales and 500 items for 5123/'2021-01-03'/'cash'. Those values should be replaced with $90 for sales, and 15 for items.

Here is my attempt (using a for loop, which doesn't work). Whenever I am using a loop and Pandas together, a red flag goes off in my head. What is the correct way to do this?

```
stores = df['Store'].unique()
payment_methods = df['Payment Method'].unique()
attributes = df['Attribute'].unique()

df_no_outliers = pd.DataFrame()

for store in stores:
    for payment_method in payment_methods:
        for attribute in attributes:

            df_temp = df.loc[df['Store'] == store]
            df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp['Payment Method'] == payment_method]
            df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp['Attribute'] == attribute]

            df_temp['Value'] = np.where(df_temp['Value'] <= (df_temp['Value'].shift(-1)
                                                                +df_temp['Value'].shift(-2))*2/2,
                                         df_temp['Value'],
                                        (df_temp['Value'].shift(-1)+df_temp['Value'].shift(-2))/2)

            df_temp['Value'] = np.where(df_temp['Value'] >= (df_temp['Value'].shift(-1)
                                                                +df_temp['Value'].shift(-2))*0.5/2,
                                         df_temp['Value'],
                                        (df_temp['Value'].shift(-1)+df_temp['Value'].shift(-2))/2)


            df_no_outliers = df_no_outliers.append(df_temp)
```

In case anyone is curious why I'm using this rolling average method instead of something like Tukey's method of cutting off data more or less than 1.5*IQR away from 1Q and 3Q, my data is timeseries over the period of COVID, which means that the IQR is very large (high sales before COVID, then a deep pit of lack of sales after), so the IQR ends up not filtering anything. I do not want to remove the COVID drop, but rather remove some erroneous data entry failures (some stores are bad about this, and may enter a few extra zeroes on some days...). Instead of using the last two days as a rolling filter, I will probably end up using 5 or 7 days (for a week). I am also open to other ways of doing this cleanup / outlier removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#groupby the required columns and compute the rolling 2-day average
average = (df.groupby(["Store","Payment Method","Attribute"], as_index=False)
           .apply(lambda x: x["Value"].rolling(2).mean().shift())
           .droplevel(0).sort_index()
           )

#divide values by the average and keep only those ratios that fall between 0.5 and 2
df['Value'] = df["Value"].where(df["Value"].div(average).fillna(1).between(0.5,2),average)
>>> df
    Store                 Date Payment Method Attribute  Value
0    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash    sales$  105.0
1    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash     items   20.0
2    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card    sales$  190.0
3    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card     items   40.0
4    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash    sales$   75.0
5    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash     items   10.0
6    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card    sales$  170.0
7    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card     items   35.0
8    5123  2021-01-03 00:00:00           cash    sales$   90.0
9    5123  2021-01-03 00:00:00           cash     items   15.0
10   5123  2021-01-03 00:00:00           card    sales$  150.0
11   5123  2021-01-03 00:00:00           card     items   20.0
```

Comment: Almost! When I do this, I lose about 10% of my data (my actual data is in the tens of millions of rows). Could you please describe what the chained methods there are doing?

Comment: Grouping by the different columns and computing the rolling 2-period mean of Value. Then we use this to filter for values between 0.5 and 2. Which part is unclear?

Comment: What is .shift() doing here? I can see that running that code without .shift() produces a series with 8 non-null entries, and running with .shift() produces the correct series with 4 non-null entries. I thought that shift moves rows down, so I would have thought that 537.5 (the last entry in the series without using .shift()) would have fallen off, leaving 7 non-null entries. Separate from the shift question, it looks like the two outlier rows were just completely removed, rather than replaced with the average, which explains why I am now missing data.

Comment: Got it. Will edit your post to show what I did. Ended up adding sort_index() to the average series, then using np.where() to fill in the initial dataframe values with the average where there used to be an outlier.

Comment: @edutt - Modified your edit slightly to using `df.where` instead of `np.where`. That eliminates the need to `import numpy` :)